# second call prctl() dont work

Tags: linux, process, fork

I try write program, which realize next idea:
After start, program using fork() and:
parent process stopped on function wait() (for waiting death child process);
child process use prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGHUP), and setup signal handler (It's helps detect parent death);
After death any process, program use fork() again.

```
void forking_process() {
  pid_t id;
  printf("forking_process is called!\n");
  if (id = fork())  {       
          parent_process_operation(); 
       } else {  
          child_process_operation();  
       }
}

void parent_process_operation() {
  int status = 0;
  printf("It's parent process! Pid = %d\n", (int)getpid());
  pid_t chid = wait(&status);
  printf("Terminated child process with PID = %d\n", chid);
  inform_about_parent_death(status);    
}

void child_process_operation() {
  printf("It's child process! pid = %d, ppid = %d\n", 
         (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
  struct sigaction sa;
  memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
  sa.sa_handler = inform_about_parent_death;
  if (sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL)) 
        fprintf(stderr, "sigaction error\n");
  prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGHUP);
  while(1) {
     printf("."); fflush(stdout);
     sleep(1);  
    }
 }

 void inform_about_parent_death(int i)  {
  printf("Process is dead. Restart!\n");
  forking_process();
 }

 int main (void) {
  forking_process();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

If I run this application, and in another terminal kill child process - then will create child process.
If I kill the parent process once, - signal handler started and call fork().
If I again kill the parent process, - signal handler not responded.
That is - prctl() in first process work, but prctl() in second child process don't work.
Why it is happen? How I can correct it's program?